# Return null on condition in sub-table

Tags: sql, mysql, database

Say i have 2 tables, person and job.

```
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| job_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| j_id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| j_name   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| j_active | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

How would i do a select where it only returns a `job_id` where `j_active = 1` and otherwise return 0 or NULL? So, I would want to **always return all persons** but when their job isn't active i dont want to return their job id

Comment: Do all persons always have a valid `job_id`?

Comment: no, some will have an ID and some will not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from person p left join job j on p.job_id=j.j_id and j.j_active=1
```

Answer (score 0):

A case statement should work.  Something like:

```
select name, case when j_active=1 then job_id else null end as job_id
from person join job on (person.job_id=job.j_id)
```